# "Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2." when installing lxml

Tags: pi-3

I'm trying to get lxml for python 3.5 on my Raspberry Pi 3 model B on Raspbian PIXEL but when I run

```
$ sudo python3.5 -m pip install lxml
```

I get this output

```
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-3.7.2.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-cfdhgwer/lxml/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-pemg5q0q-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Building lxml version 3.7.2.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: b'/bin/sh: 1: xslt-config: not found\n'
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron
    copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.5
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.5/src
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.5/src/lxml
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/local/include/python3.5m -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.5/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
    In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:515:0:
    src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:14:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
     #include "libxml/xmlversion.h"
                                   ^
    compilation terminated.
    Compile failed: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    creating tmp
    cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInity619n6iw.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInity619n6iw.o
    /tmp/xmlXPathInity619n6iw.c:1:26: fatal error: libxml/xpath.h: No such file or directory
     #include "libxml/xpath.h"
                              ^
    compilation terminated.
    *********************************************************************************
    Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
    *********************************************************************************
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-cfdhgwer/lxml/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-pemg5q0q-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-cfdhgwer/lxml/
```

What is making this happen?

Answer (score 1):

From your log:

> `** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **`

Try running:

```
sudo apt install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
```